# How is AND logic interpreted in a FOR...NEXT loop's end case?

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, logical-operators

For the below FOR loop in VB.net (a simplified version of my code), the encased logic is only hit twice.  I had assumed the end case being 10 and 50 would be interpreted as "continue if i < 10 AND i < 50" but that does not seem to be the case.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10 And 50
      '...logic...
    Next
```

What is the correct interpretation, and is there a way to create a FOR loop with multiple end cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your loop is equivalent to

```
    Dim t = 10 And 50
    For i As Integer = 0 To t
        ' something '
    Next
```

where `10 And 50` is a bitwise `AND` operation on two `Integer` numbers. And because `10 And 50` returns `2` you get loop from `0` to `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Might `And` be bitwise and?  10 = 8+2, and 50 = 32+16+2, so the bitwise and would just be 2.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the `For` statement is (edited to fit):

> `For`  *LoopControlVariable*  *Equals*  *Expression*  `To`  *Expression*   [`Step` *Expression*  ]

So the `And` keyword plays no special role in the statement, it is simply part of the `To` *expression*.  With integral operands, it performs a mathematical AND operation that performs a bitwise AND on the bits in the integral value.

Since 10 And 50 equals 00001010 And 00110010 in binary = 00000010 in binary or 2 in decimal, the loops iterates from 0 to 2 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you it to be for i<10 and i<50? Wouldn't you just need for i<50?

Comment: I replaced the variables in the For loop's To expression with the concrete values that I was seeing the issue with, to avoid drawing focus away from the question